# How to map estimated probabilities to discrete outcome variable?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-logit

I have performed a multinomial logit regression for an unbalanced data set. 
My outcome variable y can take three values: 0,1,2.

Since most of the observations are 0 - the predicted probability of y=1 for each observartion is the largest. Assume that the estimated probabilities for each subject are given by the tupel:(p_0i,p_1i,p_2i)

where i denotes subject i and 0,1,2 denote the possible alternative.

A simple rule like - max(p_0i,p_1i,p_2i)  would be therefore nonsense and allways delivering outcome 1 since it is allways the larges probability.

So my questio basically is: how to map the probabilities to the outcome 0,1,2?
Especially if I want to achieve a good calibration in terms of AUC,ROC.

It would be further helpful to get a reference to a textbook - thanks!